# remove pop up box only if login successfull

Tags: magento

we are hiding the pop up once we click on login "button", but we want to hide only if the login is successfull. [ if user enter correct email id & password ]

> Login Form

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect.....>

<label>Email Address</label>
<input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" />
<label>password</label>
<input type="password" name="login[password]"  id="pass" />

<button onclick="hideWindow()" id="send2"><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></button>
```

> controllers

```
protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath = "")
    {

        Mage::register('isSecureArea',true);    
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        $result = array(
            'success' => false
        );

        $login ="";
        $productId ="";
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login     = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            $productId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');
        }
            // echo $login['product_id'];die;
            // if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    if(isset($login) && (is_array($login) && !empty($login)) || ($login!="")){
                        $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                        $result['redirect'] = $this->_getRefererUrl() ? $this->_getRefererUrl() : Mage::getUrl('customer/account', array(
                            '_secure' => true
                        ));
                        $result['success']  = true;
                        $customerId         = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
                    }
                    else{
                        $customerId = "";
                    }

                    $product->setName($originalProduct->getName());


                    $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
                    $product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);

                    if ($doSave)
                        $product->save();
                    // To save inside my_designs

                    return $product;                   

                }
                catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    switch ($e->getCode()) {
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                            $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']));
                            break;
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                            break;
                        default:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    $result['error'] = $message;
                    $session->setUsername($login['username']);

                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    $result = "ERROR :".$e->getMesage();
                    /
                }
            // } else {
            //     $result['error'] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Login and password are required.');
            // }
        // }

        Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

        // code for guest end
    }
```

please help me for this
Thanks in Advance

> update

```
function hideWindow() 
{ 
document.getElementById('something').style.display = 'none'; 

document.getElementById('ajaxlogin-mask').style.display = 'none';
 }
```

Comment: in frontend where the form show?

Comment: @BachchaSingh in product view page.....

Comment: Check my answer you need to check the user is login or not

Comment: @raj could you please show your js code `hideWindow()`

Comment: Okay update your answer with js... So that I can help you

Comment: @SanchitGupta please check update part in question

Comment: The issue arise when user click on `Save Image` button and pop up appear and if user click on login button the pop gone away without any processing... Am I right?

Comment: @SanchitGupta yes, right, if user enter correct email id and password, than only it should hide the `pop up` when we click on `login`.....

Comment: Are you using any external extension to login user or using default magento functionality?

Comment: @SanchitGupta we are using custom module for displaying pop up, but for login, we almost using similar code as default magento, i will show full code if you want.....

Comment: Hello @raj I check your code first of all you have to make `class='required-entry'` to useremail and password input fields and validate should be ` var ajaxLoginForm = new VarienForm('ajaxlogin-login-form');` remove `true` parameter from this.

Comment: @SanchitGupta let me check that now.....

Comment: And then you have to apply ajax to login the user and so on. This process will take time to me. Because I have to write all the code from scratch. It would be best if you add ajax code in `hideWindow()` function to make user logged in if credentials pass and then hide the pop up and redirect the user to desired page otherwise show error message inside popup.

Comment: @SanchitGupta i followed as you said, added class='required-entry'  & used `var ajaxLoginForm = new VarienForm('ajaxlogin-login-form');` ` but still the same....

Comment: @raj you have to made other changes as well.

Comment: @SanchitGupta thanks, if you get free time please help me with code , until that time i willl try with google.....

Comment: Sure. you have to google it. and follow some good tutorial. Because this is not big issue. Currently I am in the office, will catch you later.

Comment: sure, thanks again....

Comment: @SanchitGupta i tried lot, but not getting any solution, can you please help me with code.....

Comment: @SanchitGupta please help with ajax code

Comment: Hello @raj, could you share your server detail?

Comment: @SanchitGupta can we hide the pop up with help of controller action instead of `ajax` once the login is successfull, than we can hide the pop up.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put condition in frontend

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
    <button onclick="hideWindow()" id="send2"><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></button>
<?php } else { ?>
    <button onclick="showWindow()" id="send2"><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></button>       
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, i will check and inform you

Comment: initially once guest user click on `save design` in on [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-5.html) , we are displaying pop up, after that in pop up form, when user enter correct details & click on login button, i want to hide pop up, but if user enter wrong details, i dont want to hide pop up. after i tried your code, the pop is not displaying after i click on `save design` button as in [link2](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) , please check once......

Comment: when i click on login popup hide either i fill wrong or write details, you need to do with ajax

Comment: yes, you are right, thats that issue, can you please me with code .....

Comment: you have to modify your code to validate user and when login or register

Comment: thanks for your reply, i am using same code hat i posted in question...... can you please check and help me......